# Get value from Observable on object property

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Given an Observable with an object which has an inner Observable as one of its properties, how is it possible to get the value of the inner observable, along with the rest of the object, from an observable chain?

Simplified example construct:

```
let obs = of({ prop1: 'foo', prop2: of('bar') })
```

The result should be

```
{ prop1: "foo", prop2: "bar" }
```

I have tried with flatMap, but was only able to get the value from the inner observable by itself, losing the rest of the object in the process.

EDIT: a slightly adapted version of Julius Dzidzevičius's answer solved my problem:

```
of({ prop1: 'foo', prop2: of('bar') }).pipe(
    switchMap(val => val.prop2,
        (a, b) => ({ prop1: a.prop1, prop2: b })
    )).subscribe(console.log)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **ResultSelector** function from a flattening operator (like `switchMap`, `flatMap` etc.):

```
obs = of({ prop1: 'foo', prop2: of('bar') }).pipe(
  switchMap(val => val.prop2,
  (a, b) => ({a, b})
).subscribe(console.log)
```